# Android app crashes when not in debugging mode

Tags: android, crash

I've made a few apps in the past but none of them have had this issue. It works while debugging in Android Studio, but if I stop debugging and attempt to open the app directly from the phone (after it's already been installed from debugging) I get "[app name]" has stopped working"

Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.[HIDDEN].[HIDDEN]">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_descriptor">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
        android:name=".WebActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <service
        android:name=".[HIDDEN]FirebaseMessagingService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Gradle (project)

```
buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.3'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.2'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Gradle (app)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.[HIDDEN].[HIDDEN]"
        minSdkVersion 22
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner 
        "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false // keeps unused methods instead of removing them
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.1.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso- 
core:3.0.2'
    api 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:15.0.1'
    api 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'
    api 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

MainActivity

```
package com.[HIDDEN].[HIDDEN];

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceId;
import com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdReceiver;

import org.json.JSONStringer;

import java.util.Date;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private TextView mTextMessage;
    private Button mOpen_uOrder;

    private BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener 
mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener
        = new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.navigation_home:
                    mTextMessage.setText(R.string.title_home);
                    return true;
                case R.id.navigation_dashboard:
                    mTextMessage.setText(R.string.title_dashboard);
                    return true;
                case R.id.navigation_notifications:
                    mTextMessage.setText(R.string.title_notifications);
                    return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    };

    private void mOpen_uOrderClicked() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, WebActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mTextMessage = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.message);
        mOpen_uOrder = (Button) findViewById(R.id.open_uOrder);
        mOpen_uOrder.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mOpen_uOrderClicked();
            }
        });
        BottomNavigationView navigation = (BottomNavigationView) 
findViewById(R.id.navigation);
    navigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener);

        Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
        if (bundle != null) {
            //TODO: Open activity specified in key `click_action`
            Log.println(Log.ASSERT, "Click Action: ", 
bundle.getString("click_action"));
        }

        [HIDDEN]FirebaseMessagingService service = new 
[HIDDEN]FirebaseMessagingService();

    }
}
```

Comment: You should also post a copy of the java class that is called when your app starts.

Comment: Hard to tell. I would try to log into some file at the start of the main activity to track down where the issue is coming from. Does it also crash with very basic MainActivity (is configuration really the source of the problem)?

Comment: Right, and it's hard to know what's causing it since it works in Debug mode, but obviously I cannot debug it when I'm just opening it from my phone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to do it the hard way and commented out everything on MainActivity and then go through line by line uncommenting 1 line, install the apk and then open from my phone to see which line is causing the error, and it was this:

```
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
if (bundle != null) {
    //TODO: Open activity specified in key `click_action`
    // THE CULPRIT:::Apparently you cannot have log statements in the app when not debugging? 
    // Because bundle.getString("click_action") works.
    Log.println(Log.ASSERT, "Click Action: ", bundle.getString("click_action"));
}
```

Comment: Log.ASSERT indicates that an unexpected thing has happened. In general, an assertion means "I ASSERT that the logical condition in this test is always true(and if it's not, that's a big error")


You should have
`Log.println(Log.INFO, ...`


**References**
------------------
(1) [Wikipedia ASSERTION(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assertion_(software_development) )
----------------

(2) [StackOverflow - How does Log.wtf differ from log.e](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9524369/how-does-log-wtf-differ-from-log-e)