# Robotium - How can I avoid Robotium to stop when the first error is detected?

Tags: robotium

Is there a way to force [Robotium](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robotium) to continue completing the whole script in cases where something fails?

For example: If I have three errors and I run the script overnight, I will only catch one error and then the script stops. I want to cycle through all of the script and then report all three errors.

Answer (score 2):

Use `try`-`catch`:

```
try { 
    //Your script
    //Write some code to print your result as pass.
}
catch(Error er){
    //Fail
    //Write some code to print your result as fail + er.getMessage());.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your class that extends ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2 you can put more methods; I think it's better if you don't put all test in one unique method.

```
public void testDisplayBlackBoxAgree() {
assertTrue(solo.searchText("Agree"));
}

public void testDisplayBlackBoxDisagree() {
assertTrue(solo.searchText("Disagree"));
}
```

I hope this integration to other answer received could help you.

Sorry for my english!

Answer (score 0):

I usually type something like

if (solo.searchText("example")==true){

write code
}

else{
write code for what's supposed to happen if the scenario fails
}

Answer (score 0):

You can use try-catches like previously mentioned  but you can also make your own assert function that prints the failure data to a document with the stacktrace using the method described here "[How do I find the caller of a method using stacktrace or reflection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/421280/in-java-how-do-i-find-the-caller-of-a-method-using-stacktrace-or-reflection)".

Another way to do this is to print the data to logcat if you want to process it while the app is still running mentioned here "[How do I write outputs to the Log in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2364811/how-do-i-write-outputs-to-the-log-in-android)". In all you don't have to use the AssertTrue or AssertFalse functions they are just a helpful tool. Hope this helps