# java.lang.Stringcannot be convert to JSONObject

Tags: php, android-studio

i am going to use register.java to insert data through php file to web database.But when i key in data an click on button register , the data does insert into the database and logcat show the 2 error below .how could i fix it ?i have try alot that wat could i do but still stuck at the 'value

RegisterActivity.java

```
   'public class RegisterActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);

    final EditText etName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etName);
    final EditText etUsername = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etUsername);
    final EditText etPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etPassword);

    final Button bRegister = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bRegister);

    bRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            final String name = etName.getText().toString();
            final String username = etUsername.getText().toString();
            final String password = etPassword.getText().toString();


            Response.Listener<String> responseListener = new Response.Listener<String>(){
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    try {
                        JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(response);
                        boolean success = jsonResponse.getBoolean("SUCCESS");
    Log.w("eeee", response.toString());


                        if(success){
                            Intent intent = new Intent(RegisterActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
                            RegisterActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
                        }else{
                            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(RegisterActivity.this);
                            builder.setMessage("Register Failed")
                                    .setNegativeButton("Retry", null)
                                    .create()
                                    .show();
                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e){
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            };

            RegisterRequest registerRequest = new RegisterRequest(name, username, password, responseListener );
            RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(RegisterActivity.this);
            queue.add(registerRequest);
        }
    });
}
    }
```

Register.php

```
<?php
$con=mysql_connect("mysql.hostinger.my","user","password","mydb");


$name=$_POST["name"];

$password=$_POST["password"];
$username=$_POST["username"];
$statement= mysqli_prepare($con,"INSERT INTO user(name,username,password) VALUES (?,?,?)");
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement,"sss",$name,$username,$password);
mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);

$response = array();
$response = ["SUCCESS"];

echo json_encode($response);
    ?>
```

the 2 error :

```
    'D/Volley: [241] BasicNetwork.logSlowRequests: HTTP response for request=<[ ]  http://finalpro.16mb.com/android/Register.php  0x7ef3eea4 NORMAL 1>  [lifetime=3410], [size=843], [rc=200], [retryCount=0]
    W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: Value <br of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
```

Comment: Did you insert a "<br" as an input? (name/username/password)

Comment: u mean in the .xml file?

Comment: I mean in the editText(s)

Comment: @Tony
'<EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/etName"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:hint="Name" />'

This is my editText , but i never find any <br , but the app keep show <br type

Comment: Can you please log the response inside OnResponse and share it? Like Log.w("eeee", response.toString());

Comment: what is Log.w?
what is need for replace the eee?
omg,i feel that i so stupid

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2364811/how-do-i-write-outputs-to-the-log-in-android

Comment: i still not understand where should i put the log.w , may u share the code for me?

Comment: put it after "boolean success = jsonResponse.getBoolean("SUCCESS");"

Comment: 'boolean success = jsonResponse.getBoolean("SUCCESS");
                            Log.w("eeee", response.toString());'

Comment: i copy wat the logcat show at the bottom

Comment: i have edit on my code , can you help me check is that correct or not?

Comment: ..it is correct but not to make it work, we just want to see what data "response" variable holds. Run the app, and look at the Log tab, search for "eeee"

Comment: i just see this 'Gralloc pipe failed'
.other in the logcat does not see the 'eee'

Comment: the java.lang error will not show . But now it show 
'D/NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using platform default' and 'W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.example.user.loginregister-1/lib/x86' and 
W/gralloc_ranchu: Gralloc pipe failed'