# Notification didn't pop up after firebase function was fired

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I am relatively new to Android Dev't and have a problem. I tried implementing firebase functions to send notifications to my android application when certain data was saved to my firebase realtime database. But after the data is saved and function is executed, it says in the logs that it is successfully sent but I don't receive any notification pop up on my android test device. What could be the problem? Below is my code.

My JS code.

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');

admin.initializeApp();

exports.sendNotification = functions.database.ref('/Lecture_Materials/{MIS}/{MISId}/name')
.onWrite(( change,context) =>{

// Grab the current value of what was written to the Realtime Database.
var eventSnapshot = change.after.val();
var str1 = "Lecture material uploaded is: " + eventSnapshot.name;
console.log(eventSnapshot);

var topic = "Management.Information.System";
var payload = {
    data: {
        name: str1,
    }
};

// Send a message to devices subscribed to the provided topic.
return admin.messaging().sendToTopic(topic, payload)
    .then(function (response) {
        // See the MessagingTopicResponse reference documentation for the
        // contents of response.
        console.log("Successfully sent message:", response);
        return;
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
        console.log("Error sending message:", error);
    });
    });
```

My OnMessageReceived

```
package com.dreamlazerstudios.gtuconline;

import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.RingtoneManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;

import com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService;
import com.google.firebase.messaging.RemoteMessage;

public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {
@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {

    // Check if message contains a data payload.
    if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {
        showNotification(remoteMessage.getData().get("name"));
    }

    // Check if message contains a notification payload.
    if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {

    }
}

private void showNotification(String name) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0 /* Request code */, intent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

    Uri defaultSoundUri= RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setContentTitle("Lecture note uploaded is: " + name)
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .setContentText("Lecture Notes")
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

    NotificationManager notificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    notificationManager.notify(0 /* ID of notification */, notificationBuilder.build());
}
}
```

Any help is deeply appreciated.

Comment: You send to a topic in JS, but don't listen the topic in Android. So you should listen & subscribe to topic you sent. https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/topic-messaging

Comment: Any code snippet to help me with?

Comment: How do I go about that??

Comment: You can find in the link i sent.

Comment: It's difficult to understand

Comment: It's difficult to understand

Comment: Did you subscribe to topics in your android code?

Comment: Yes Rohit. I did.

Comment: Did you register FirebaseMessagingServices services in your menifest?

Comment: Yes please. I certainly did

Comment: Then, Can you add log in android code and check what value it is receiving ? & as well as please check the log details of function

Comment: The log details of the function are accurate Rohit. How do I log in android code?

Comment: use debug log to see whether data is recieved in your app or not, please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2364811/how-do-i-write-outputs-to-the-log-in-android  for how to use log in android

Comment: Didn't work out

Comment: Rohit. It works now. But it says eventsnapshot.name is "undefined"....What could be the problem now?

Comment: Okay finally it worked. But it seems a user has to subscribe more than once before the notification is received....what could be wrong

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to send push notification, so you need to do some necessary implementations for firebase cloud messaging. Also in server side, you need push notification key for your application to send notification.

You can check the following documentation to see how to implement Firebase Cloud Messaging in client side (Also you can use Firebase assistant tool in Android Studio, you can find it in **Tools>Firebase**):

https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client

For the server side, to send notification you can follow the below guide:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/admin/send-messages

In addition, you can also use some 3rd party libraries like:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/fcm-push

Comment: The method I'm using is supposed to work. The documentation is somehow vague.