# How to fix "There is no public dispose() method in the class d.g.b$a" in androidstudio release build

Tags: java, android, android-studio, runtime-error

When Compiling my app in the debug build, I get no errors. But when compiled in release, I get runtime errors.

I have no clue where on earth to start with this, as all of the pointers go to an unknown source.

I have been unable to replicate this error because as said before, none of the pointers are helpful, so I don't know what/where the problem has came from

Below is the runtime error.

```
2019-11-02 21:12:45.696 22451-22471/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: GLThread 37524
    Process: flappy.birb, PID: 22451
    java.lang.RuntimeException: There is no public dispose() method in the class d.g.b$a
        at d.c.a.c(Unknown Source:5)
        at d.c.a.b(Unknown Source:99)
        at d.c.a.a(Unknown Source:64)
        at d.g.b.<init>(Unknown Source:203)
        at d.g.b.a(Unknown Source:6)
        at d.g.g.<init>(Unknown Source:10)
        at d.g.a.<init>(Unknown Source:0)
        at d.g.f.<init>(Unknown Source:0)
        at flappy.birb.a.v0(Unknown Source:4)
        at flappy.birb.a.f0(Unknown Source:3)
        at flappy.birb.a.S(Unknown Source:16)
        at d.c.a.u(Unknown Source:62)
        at d.f.j$b.onDrawFrame(Unknown Source:13)
        at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1580)
        at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1275)
```

---

it's not a nullpointer error, so suggested post doesn't help.
If it was a nullpointer I would be getting it in my debug build, which as said earlier, does not happen.

---

> you have to configure proguard properly. if have you used an external
>   library, copy their proguard rules as well
>   -Touhidul Islam

.

> Seems someone ran an obfuscator on the code, and didn't do it right. If
>   that your code that's been obfuscated? – Andreas

I removed all the obsufcation stuff I pasted in from [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code), so now I get the error in new detail, shown below

---

```
2019-11-04 11:38:00.176 773-832/? E/ANDR-PERF-MPCTL: Invalid profile no. 0, total profiles 0 only
2019-11-04 11:38:00.716 16476-16476/? E/Finsky: [2] zdo.b(2): Package name null is not an installed package
2019-11-04 11:38:00.954 15361-20380/? E/CastSocket: [TcpProberDeviceController-2] Failed to shutdown the output stream socket: pjq@5035be3.
    java.net.SocketException: Socket is not connected
2019-11-04 11:38:00.956 15361-18054/? E/TcpProberDeviceController: [TcpProberDeviceController-2] onSocketConnectionFailed. Error: 3
2019-11-04 11:38:00.958 15361-20380/? E/CastSocket: [TcpProberDeviceController-1] Failed to shutdown the output stream socket: pjq@785d33f.
    java.net.SocketException: Socket is not connected
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.translateToSocketException(Net.java:129)
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.translateException(Net.java:166)
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.translateException(Net.java:172)
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketAdaptor.shutdownOutput(SocketAdaptor.java:424)
        at pit.b(:com.google.android.gms@19530037@19.5.30 (100400-275531062):9)
        at piw.c(:com.google.android.gms@19530037@19.5.30 (100400-275531062):24)
        at piv.run(:com.google.android.gms@19530037@19.5.30 (100400-275531062):6)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
     Caused by: java.nio.channels.NotYetConnectedException
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.shutdownOutput(SocketChannelImpl.java:844)
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketAdaptor.shutdownOutput(SocketAdaptor.java:422)
        at pit.b(:com.google.android.gms@19530037@19.5.30 (100400-275531062):9) 
        at piw.c(:com.google.android.gms@19530037@19.5.30 (100400-275531062):24) 
        at piv.run(:com.google.android.gms@19530037@19.5.30 (100400-275531062):6) 
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764) 
2019-11-04 11:38:02.708 1269-1269/? E/LoadedApk: Unable to instantiate appComponentFactory
    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.support.v4.app.CoreComponentFactory" on path: DexPathList[[],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.google.android.gms-NozBfal7CK1AQkWLZL5VBA==/lib/arm64, /data/app/com.google.android.gms-NozBfal7CK1AQkWLZL5VBA==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /system/lib64]]
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:134)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
        at android.app.LoadedApk.createAppFactory(LoadedApk.java:226)
        at android.app.LoadedApk.updateApplicationInfo(LoadedApk.java:346)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleDispatchPackageBroadcast(ActivityThread.java:5633)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1880)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at com.android.server.SystemServer.run(SystemServer.java:503)
        at com.android.server.SystemServer.main(SystemServer.java:339)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:537)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:838)
2019-11-04 11:38:02.711 20727-20774/? E/libc: Access denied finding property "persist.vendor.fps.history.enabled"
2019-11-04 11:38:02.712 1269-1269/? E/LoadedApk: Unable to instantiate appComponentFactory
    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.support.v4.app.CoreComponentFactory" on path: DexPathList[[],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.google.android.gms-NozBfal7CK1AQkWLZL5VBA==/lib/arm64, /data/app/com.google.android.gms-NozBfal7CK1AQkWLZL5VBA==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /system/lib64]]
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:134)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
        at android.app.LoadedApk.createAppFactory(LoadedApk.java:226)
        at android.app.LoadedApk.updateApplicationInfo(LoadedApk.java:346)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleDispatchPackageBroadcast(ActivityThread.java:5633)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1880)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at com.android.server.SystemServer.run(SystemServer.java:503)
        at com.android.server.SystemServer.main(SystemServer.java:339)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:537)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:838)
2019-11-04 11:38:02.814 20727-20774/? E/libc: Access denied finding property "persist.vendor.hwui.skia.multithread.enabled"
2019-11-04 11:38:02.814 20727-20774/? E/libc: Access denied finding property "persist.vendor.hwui.skia.reduce.overdraw.enabled"
2019-11-04 11:38:02.819 1269-1605/? E/OnePlusSmartBoostManager: Exception : file not exits :/proc/20704/memplus_type
2019-11-04 11:37:44.900 20626-20644/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: GLThread 41015
    Process: flappy.birb, PID: 20626
    java.lang.RuntimeException: There is no public dispose() method in the class d.g.b$a
        at d.c.a.c(Unknown Source:5)
        at d.c.a.b(Unknown Source:99)
        at d.c.a.a(Unknown Source:64)
        at d.g.b.<init>(Unknown Source:203)
        at d.g.b.a(Unknown Source:6)
        at d.g.g.<init>(Unknown Source:10)
        at d.g.a.<init>(Unknown Source:0)
        at d.g.f.<init>(Unknown Source:0)
        at flappy.birb.a.t0(Unknown Source:4)
        at flappy.birb.a.f0(Unknown Source:3)
        at flappy.birb.a.S(Unknown Source:16)
        at d.c.a.u(Unknown Source:62)
        at d.f.j$b.onDrawFrame(Unknown Source:13)
        at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1580)
        at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1275)
2019-11-04 11:38:02.845 20727-20772/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: GLThread 41023
    Process: flappy.birb, PID: 20727
    java.lang.RuntimeException: There is no public dispose() method in the class d.g.b$a
        at d.c.a.c(Unknown Source:5)
        at d.c.a.b(Unknown Source:99)
        at d.c.a.a(Unknown Source:64)
        at d.g.b.<init>(Unknown Source:203)
        at d.g.b.a(Unknown Source:6)
        at d.g.g.<init>(Unknown Source:10)
        at d.g.a.<init>(Unknown Source:0)
        at d.g.f.<init>(Unknown Source:0)
        at flappy.birb.a.t0(Unknown Source:4)
        at flappy.birb.a.f0(Unknown Source:3)
        at flappy.birb.a.S(Unknown Source:16)
        at d.c.a.u(Unknown Source:62)
        at d.f.j$b.onDrawFrame(Unknown Source:13)
        at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1580)
        at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1275)
```

---

> @F53 It might be because of conflict resolution, on solving
>   dependecies. Can you share your gradle file. – GensaGames

```java
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    signingConfigs {
        release {
            storeFile file('C:\\Users\\example\\documents\\AndroidStudio\\example.jks')
            storePassword 'examplepass'
            keyAlias = 'thisisanexample'
            keyPassword 'examplepass'
        }
    }
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        multiDexEnabled true
        applicationId "flappy.birb"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 2
        versionName '0.2 - AlphaBirb'
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }      
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            debuggable true
        }
        release {
            /*// Enables code shrinking, obfuscation, and optimization for only
            // your project's release build type.
            minifyEnabled true

            // Enables resource shrinking, which is performed by the
            // Android Gradle plugin.
            shrinkResources true

            // Includes the default ProGuard rules files that are packaged with
            // the Android Gradle plugin. To learn more, go to the section about
            // R8 configuration files.
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile(
                    'proguard-android-optimize.txt'),
                    'proguard-rules.pro'*/
        }
    }
    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }
    buildToolsVersion = '28.0.3'
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.support:wearable:2.5.0'
    compileOnly 'com.google.android.wearable:wearable:2.5.0'
    implementation files('libs/processing-core.jar')    
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

Comment: Seems someone ran an obfuscator on the code, and didn't do it right. If that your code that's been obfuscated?

Comment: you have to configure proguard properly. if have you used an external library, copy their proguard rules as well

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there any solution for get errors in logcat in android api 19?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57018624/is-there-any-solution-for-get-errors-in-logcat-in-android-api-19)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like your `proguard` just cleaning up that source. Add next configuration to your `proguard` files. For more information, [check out this resource](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code).

```
-keep class <class where dispose is called>.** {
  *;
  }
```

**UPDATE:**

To ensure, it's not a `proguard` issue you need to disable it manually. Try to set up next options for your build types.

```
    minifyEnabled false
    useProguard false
```

Comment: After removing obfuscation entirely, I still get the error mentioning dispose. I never call dispose in my own code either.

Comment: @F53 It might be because of conflict resolution, on solving dependecies. Can you share your gradle file.

Comment: Yes @GensaGames