# What is TAG in log.d(TAG, message)?

Tags: java, android, logging

I want to **log** a **Catch exception** in the **log cat** but i **don't know** the **tags** of **log.d**. Can someone help me?
in all examples is see this `log.d(TAG, message)` but I don't know what goes in this **TAG**, please help me.

I tried this for example `log.d(Error, "Error: " + e)` but it didn't work.
I **searched on google** for example **log.d Tags** or **log.d Tags** and more.

Comment: please have a look at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2364811/how-do-i-write-outputs-to-the-log-in-android)

Comment: I've have an solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In TAG, you can pass anything. You can filter the logcat easily using TAG value.  In other words, it is used to group different errors under the same tag.

Comment: Create a `private static final String TAG = "MyApp/"` at the top of each class, appending a short name for the class. Then filter Logcat with MyApp and you'll be able to quickly and easily see all of your debug/error information.

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer i can make this `log.d("[Error]", "ERROR: " + e.toString());`